# Making sure only one user is editing a form in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, I have a Rails application whose edit form is on a separate edit page. Is there a way to make sure no two users are accessing the edit page at the same time? Or a user can only access the edit page if no other user is currently on the page?

Or to ask a simpler question, is there a way to get a list of users currently on the page?

I am on Rails 4.

Comment: just wondering, will a gem for user tracking be any help in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless protocol.  It was designed to allow idempotent transactions.  The server does not store transaction state information about each chain of requests. The session allows you to mitigate this design pattern and allow the server to track where your users have been.  In order for you to know if a user is on a page, you will need to store in your database where each user is.  Remember, that when a user decides to navigate away from a page, your servers will not know it, only when a request is made to a different page.

I assume you don't need to track anonymous session information, so you probably need to override your controller action that ensures users are logged in to save where the user is at.  Before rendering the page, ensure the count of user's current location equal to the rendered page is 0.

You can have AJAX fire on the page, updating the location of your user on these pages so you can ensure that there has been no user in a reasonable timeout.  Without the AJAX you would need to consider what the reasonable amount of time a user would be editing information, and consider that a non-reasonable amount of time is likely the actual amount.

There's no 'RAILS' feature that can be turned on to check where a user is located, this would be a roll your own situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a Redis Store (or anything in memory), or make a temporary sessions table for that.
Then you can authorize the show action to check whatever you want.